# jqgrid json data not working with json_decode

Tags: php, javascript, json, jqgrid

I have a json string that is posted to the server that looks like this:

```
{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"screen_name\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"aaa\"}]}
```

It looks pretty good to me, but the problem is the PHP function `json_decode` returns NULL.  I made a codepad example that illustrates the problem here : http://codepad.org/SOJw9cZb.  What do I have to do to this string to get json_decode to work properly?

This json string is sent to the server by the jqgrid [Filter Toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) module to identify the search parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: json data is not valid, validate ur json here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', '{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"screen_name\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"aaa\"}]}')));
```

works just fine. i.e. convert the \" to "

Valid JSON is

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"screen_name","op":"bw","data":"aaa"}]}
```

Comment: Yes I found this too, I am wondering why jgGrid is passing my script invalid json string

Comment: Sorry - no idea. They probably thought it safer to pre-escape the double quotes just like PHP 3 did (and has since removed). Which brings me to another thought - use strip_slashes() instead :)